# Calling data using ajax on button click not working on the same button for a second click

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I have a button which opens a Bootstrap modal popup and is populated with rows of data using datatables. This works fine. When the button is clicked it runs an Ajax request to get the data and displays it in the modal window. I can see the Ajax request in the console workings.

The modal popup has a "Close" button which dismises the modal, i.e close it. If I then click the button again to open the same modal the Ajax request is not seen in the console window which in turn does not reload the data. I need the Ajax request to fire each time the button is clicked to get any changes to the data.

Can anyone see why the second button click is not calling the dataTables Ajax script. My logic tells me that each time the button is clicked the Ajax call should run. If I refresh the page, the button click works as I would expect it to.

The Button:

```
<a  class="cursoritem" data-toggle="modal" id="room_override_data_modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Room override</a>
```

The Modal window:

```
<div id="open_current_room_display_overrides_data_modal" class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="false" style="z-index:111">
  <div class="modal-wayfinder-signage" modal-ku style=" max-height:85%;  margin-top: 35px; margin-bottom:50px;" modal-lg>
    <div class="modal-content-search"> 
      <!-- END -->
      <div class="modal-header-current-signage">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <div class="modal-title-current-signage" id="HideTitle" style="cursor:move">Current room display override schedule.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body-room-override">

    <table name="timeline" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped" id="roomoverrideTable" style="width:100%; min-width:800px" data-role="datatable"   data-info="false">
      <thead>
        <tr class="CenterHeaderSignageData">
          <th><div class="LeftPadding">Room</div></th>
          <th><div class="ImagePadding">Image</div></th>
          <th>Promotion</th>
          <th>From</th>
          <th>To</th>
          <th><div class="RightPadding"></div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="CurrentSignage-rows">
      </tbody>
    </table>

      </div>
      <div class="footer_search_buttons">
          <div class="room-overide-message">Room overrides take priority if the room has a booking</div>
      <div id="foot-button-margin-current-room-display-override-schedule">
    <button id="NewRoomOverrideform" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">New override</button>
    <button id="NewRoomOverridecancelform" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-edit btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The dataTables and Ajax call

```
$(document).on("click", "#room_override_data_modal", function() {
var hotelid ='<?php echo $_SESSION['_amember_user']['hotelid'];?>';
  $('#open_current_room_display_overrides_data_modal').modal('show');
  $(".modal-body-room-override").css("padding",'2px');
   $(".modal-body-room-override").css("margin",'2px');
  var imagepath = '../../../../conf/conf_images/roomoverride/' + hotelid + '/';
  $('#roomoverrideTable').DataTable({
   "ordering": false,
        retrieve: true,
        paging: false,
    searching: false,
        bInfo : false,
        responsive: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
   ajax: {
      url: 'get_room_override.php', 
      dataSrc: ''
      
   },
   "columnDefs": [
    { className:"model-left-margin", "targets": [ 0 ] }
  ],
   language: {
      "emptyTable": "There are no promotional signage schedules set"
    },

    columns: [
      { data: 'RoomName',"sWidth": "15%" },
      { data: "PromoImage", "sWidth": "15%",  render : function (data, type, full, meta) 
                     { return '<img src="' + imagepath + '' +data+'" class="WayfinderSignageImageModal"/>'; }
      },
      { data: 'ClientName', "sWidth": "30%" },
      { data: 'PromotionFromDate', "sWidth": "20%" },
      { data: 'PromotionToDate',  "sWidth": "15%"},

      { data: 'RecordID',  render : function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var recordid = full.RecordID;
                    console.log("RECORDID", recordid);
                     return '<input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" data-id=' + recordid + ' class="btn btn-conf-view btn-xs edit_room_override">' }
      
     },
    ]

  });
});
```

Comment: why not use the modal open event show.bs.modal instead of the on click event

Comment: Hi, if I change from "$(document).bind("click", "#room_override_data_modal", function() {" to "$('#room_override_data_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {" and click the button nothing happens, the modal does not open. So I must be using this incorrectly?

Comment: @John Bright Hi, if I add  "processing": true, "destroy": true, clicking on the button does not open the modal. I did look at using your line of code earlier but had this problem. But thanks for looking/

Comment: @John Bright Bootstrap 3